# Rules for returning return type in case of Exception

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

When I have a code like below, Compiler complains that "test() method must return a result of type int"

```
class ExecptionExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Result :"+test());
    }
    private static int test(){
        try{
            System.out.println("In try");
            throw new StackOverflowError("SOError");
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("In catch");
            //throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
        } finally{
            System.out.println("In finally");
            //throw new RuntimeException();
        }
        System.out.println("Outside try-catch");
        //return 0;
    }
}
```

If I uncomment last line "return 0" then it compile and run but control never reaches at "return 0" and never prints "Outside try-catch"

Consider code below,

```
class ExecptionExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Result :"+test());
    }
    private static int test(){
        try{
            System.out.println("In try");
            throw new StackOverflowError("SOError");
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("In catch");
            //throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
        } finally{
            System.out.println("In finally");
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
        //System.out.println("Outside try-catch");
        //return 0;
    }
}
```

In above code, compiler doesn't complain about "return int value required".

So how things work? what is the rule that compiler checks for return required and not?

I am thinking as finally block is always going to be executed (leaving few  conditions) and  `RuntimeException` is thrown in finally, so compiler doesn't require return int value? Please confirm my understanding.

I am aware that `StackOverflowError` is not catch by `Exception`.

**I just want to confirm one thing, in finally block it throws unchecked exception, is that the cause that compiler will not check return? because throwing unchecked exception from try block without finally block requires return and with finally block it doesn't requires return.**

Comment: `I am aware that StackOverflowError is not catch by Exception` - If you are then I think that would answer your question

Comment: Ofcourse throwing an exception "bypasses" the return value. Otherwise you would always have to return some integer from that function, not knowing that an exception/error occured.

Comment: The question the compiler asks is "Is there a PATH, that can lead to a point where no exception is thrown and no return is given for a non-void method?". It does not ask "Will this path ever be used?" In your first example, your StackOverflowError is not an Exception, but a throwable, so it is not caught and thus gets outside, bypassing your return 0 and system out. But the compiler, cannot, for example, know if your first system out will not result in a NullPointerException, which WOULD be caught - and thus get to the end, where only a return 0 will make the method valid.

Comment: Why downvote? is it wrong question? I already wrote what I think the cause is, one can confirm that.

Comment: Did you try uncommenting out the `System.out.println("Outside try-catch");` for your second example?

Comment: yes. I tried and it gave unreachable code. I just want to confirm one thing, in finally block it throws unchecked exception, is that the cause that compiler will not check return? because throwing unchecked exception from try block without finally block requires return and with finally block it doesn't requires return.

Comment: That is your answer, it is unreachable code. Your finally is throwing an exception and you will never reach the end of the method. You cannot put any code there, not just that you don't need it. On the flip side in your first example, the compiler cannot determine that the last line is unreachable as Florian pointed out.

Comment: Here is an [example](http://ideone.com/2VKA9v) that doesn't use an exception.

Comment: Thanks Matt for example: So I can say whatever is wrote in finally will decide whether return type is required or not? If it throws exception in finally then return is not required, if it doesn't throw exception then return is required.

Comment: It is not that it throws an exception, it is the control flow. In the example I showed it uses a return instead of an exception.

Comment: @Jayesh Please refer Khalid Mughal book for java SCJP. you will get the concept more clearly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is because finally you are throwing a `RuntimeException` which will always be thrown before returning anything from the function.

Now if you put return statement in try block. The Exception will still be thrown because finally block is executed just before returning data (*but after executing return statement*). But compiler will not give you any error.

But if you put a return statement after try-catch block compiler will give you an error. It is because try-catch block itself is throwing an exception and compiler will never reach the code written afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

whatever `finally` block returns will be the final value of Method actually.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Result :"+test());
    }
    private static int test(){
        try{
            System.out.println("In try");
            return 5;

        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("In catch");
            return 5;
        } finally{
            System.out.println("In finally");
            return 10;  //finally return will be the final Return

        }
       // System.out.println("Outside try-catch");
        //return 0;
    }
```

Output will be Printed as `10` . It means whatever `finally` block returns will be the final value of method `test()`.

Now came to your  Question.

> **Question 1** . Compiler complains that `test() method must return a result of type int` ?

Ans:- It is must to return type or sub-type Variable if you define a method with `return`  type except `void`. In void there is no need to `return` any value.

> **Question 2** :  I romove the comment from last line `return 0` then it compile and run but control never reaches at "return 0" and never prints "Outside try-catch". Why ?

Ans:- this will compiles fine because one `return` value which is required is fulfilled by just removing your comments of line `return 0`.

but in your try block

```
 throw new StackOverflowError("SOError"); // throwing an error which cannot be handled using Exception Handler in Catch Block
```

`StackOverflowError` is an `error` not an `Exception` . So, It will not catched in `catch` Block. So, After `finally` block your method will be **terminated**. Control will never go to this Statement.

```
 System.out.println("Outside try-catch");
```

> **Question 3** : Why compiler doesn't complain about `return int value required`??

Ans:- `finally` block throwing an `Exception` which will be the final `Exception` statement will be executed and there is no `catch` block to handle this. So, Method `test()` will be terminated without taking care of any return value and delegate the `Exception` to the Caller Statement (which is main Here).
So, It will `compiles` fine but prone to an `Exception`.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you encounter an exception, the program breaks and displays the exception. It does not matter whether it reaches the return value or not. This is to prevent any unwanted conditions to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for try-catch-finally blocks and how they are executed. There is a lot of information about it (http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/basic-try-catch-finally.html).

As finally block will always executes in the first example, where you only do syso, the method does not end that is why return is required. In the second one you throw runtime, which ends the method execution.